# How do I unlock Dell T610 case?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, hardware

I've just got a Dell PowerEdge T610 server. The case is locked and looks like it needs a flattish key to open. Two circular ended keys came with the server, but they fit the front of the case, not the side.

Is there a trick to it, or did I get the wrong type of key with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Watch this [YouTube unboxing video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2i9eVKg6Gs).  The key is attached inside the front bezel.  He uses the round end of the key to open the side panel @2:30.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Dell servers dont need a key, the part that looks like it needs a flattish key doesn't take a key at all - a small coin will do it.